# Is there a way to download Drupal without any included Documentation?

Tags: 7

Drupal comes with heavy Documentation. Many files sometimes have more documentation than code in that file.

Is there a way to download Drupal files without the included Documentation?

Also, if I do find such a version of Drupal, will there be any performance improvement in my Drupal site?

Comment: Downvotes? I would welcome any comments explaining why?

Comment: _will there be any performance improvement in my Drupal site?_ Not unless you have a seriously mis-configured web server

Comment: @Clive: I don't understand..

Comment: I dare to guess it's the case of "lack of minimal understanding" that causes downvotes.

Comment: I guess the documentation shouldn't affect the performance of the site, and adding a documentation is for the purpose. Also if you are really concerned about the performance than give a look at: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/724/why-is-drupal-7-so-slow

Comment: I may have overstated that - I would personally consider a production PHP web server that doesn't have appropriate opcode caching to be "seriously mis-configured". You may not agree with that, however. Either way, removing comments from code files won't get you any performance gain. Concentrate on optimising _your_ code and get a sysadmin to make sure your server is set up properly

Comment: @Dipak : welcome to stackexchange. It is not the documentation that is going to hurt the performance of the site, but the bad code will. If you have enough memory running in your server, I am sure these documentation are of no hurdles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to download Drupal and it's module without documentation that is provided in comments. If you are really concerned about performance, use [opcode cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_accelerator), for example [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) - it will store precompiled opcode in memory, so the comments will not need to be loaded at each request.

PHP engine is pretty well optimized at skipping non-code parts of PHP files, so the memory requirement is the only thing that may really hit you. Exception are primarily-HTML files - getting in and out of `<?php ?>` blocks costs a minuscule amount of CPU power, so constructs like `<?php /* some docs */ ?>` adds a tiny bit of load on CPU - but again, you shouldn't be able to fill the difference, and if you are, opcode caching is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: you don't need it. It does not provide almost any significant performance improvements and if you would make such package/distribution yourself, you would need to filter out the comments/documentation in core and all additional modules yourself. This would make it extremely hard to debug, learn from source, extend and most of all maintain after updates for documented Drupal are published.

There are many ways to improve performance of a Drupal site. Start reading about APC, caching strategies and best site building techniques to learn about that.

Comment: *Any* is a pretty big word, and untrue - files are, indeed, loaded into memory with all what's in them, including comments, and php blocks costs CPU, too (I've tested), so when they are introduced only to contain comment they slow execution a tiny bit. So, no *significant* performance improvements on *properly configured* webserver, OK, but *any* is exaggeration.

Comment: Hahaha - you're reading my mind :) I was thinking about that exactly before I wrote the answer, but it would be negligent and really silly to take it into account considering other things that have an impact on performance. When you get to the point that you really *need* to process source files and strip comments before deployment, you should move on to a custom solution rather than using Drupal. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not wrong, just a bit inaccurate ;) but yes, if removing comments makes any significant difference, then something went terribly wrong.

Comment: Answer updated! :)